# Change icon sweetalert with image

Tags: sweetalert2

I want to ask how can I change `icon` image in `sweetalert` with image?

I've tried change `icon` image in `Swal.fire` with image from `assets`, but it's not working

Here's the script

```
Swal.fire({
    icon: "<?= base_url(); ?>assets/addon-media/icon_information.png",
    html: "Are you sure want to add this ?",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Sure',
    cancelButtonText: 'No, Cancel',
})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the image for an icon by using the `iconHtml` param. Also, if you'd like to remove the default border around the icon, use the `customClass` param.

Here's the example:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Image icon',
  iconHtml: '<img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100">',
  customClass: {
    icon: 'no-border'
  }
})
```

```css
.no-border {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```